Ubuntu is breaking as soon as Nvidia driver is installed
I'm no expert, but I'll try to describe my problem as well as I can.
I have recently bought a new Dell G15
Specs: 13th gen Intel Core i7 13650HX; NVIDIA GeForce RTX 43050, 6GB; Ubuntu 24.10 offical ISO from bootable flashdrive.
The installation occurs normally, but the default Nouveau drive for GPU does not work for my RTX. So I try to install the compatible NVIDIA driver (I've tried 560 and 535, both open kernel and not for each) from the Other Drivers part of the Software and Updates that come with Ubuntu.
After the requested restart, the system works normally for up to 15 seconds, then completely freezes and breaks, never to return. I was a few times able to enter settings and check that now the system recognized my GPU.
I also tried the option of installing Ubuntu along with Nvidia drivers, but the problem is the same. The system will work for about 15 seconds and freeze. Sometimes it doesn't even make it to the login screen.
Sometimes is auto-shuts down and restarts, only for it to happen again.
I have installed the OS with many different BIOS configs, including RAID, AHCI, secure boot, normal boot, all with the same exact problem.
tldr: nvidia driver installs -> restart -> system freezes or breaks
I am no expert, but not a complete noob either. I can follow instructions and enter commands in the terminal. I would deeply appreciate any help.

To fix your NVIDIA driver issue, you can install the latest NVIDIA driver by running the following:
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
 sudo reboot

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.
Install a newer kernel:
 sudo apt install linux-image-6.5.0-051600-generic
 sudo reboot

Blacklist Nouveau driver:
 sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf

Add the following to the file:
 blacklist nouveau
 options nouveau modeset=0

Then run:
 sudo update-initramfs -u
 sudo reboot

Add this to GRUB for NVIDIA power management:
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Modify:
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"

Then update GRUB:
 sudo update-grub
 sudo reboot

Switch to LightDM:
 sudo apt install lightdm
 sudo reboot

Check logs for errors:
journalctl -xe | grep -i nvidia

edit: This took me so long to write. Let me know if this works!

You may need to uninstall old nVidia drivers before installing new one. They can conflict & cause issues. sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*

Sir, I thank you for your time. I feel a bit bad because I was able to solve the issue and came here to respond to my own question when I saw your response. I hope that someone sees this post in the future and your solution works for them. I hope you don't get frustrated, we need people like you!

And God bless your kind soul

I was able to solve it by myself. What I did was:
On BIOS, no secure boot, AHCI storage and hybrid graphics on.

Fresh install of Ubuntu 24.10, when presented with the option to install with NVIDIA drivers or with WiFi connection, DO NOT CHECK THE BOXES. Procede with default installation and erase the Hard Drive.

When the installation is completed, open command prompt and sudo apt upgrade, after that, enter sudo apt update and reboot.

gcc must be installed as a requirement for CUDA. If you check for it and can't find it, like I did, just sudo apt update, followed by sudo apt install build-essential. Check if everything worked out fine with gcc --version. I got all this from here.

Install Nvidia CUDA. Just follow all instructions here.

Then install the nvidia driver following the instructions from here. Make sure to use the drivers for generic use with sudo ubuntu-drivers install

DO NOT REBOOT YET

Then open the Additional Drivers App that comes with Ubuntu and make sure that the latest proprietary nvidia driver is selected.

Reboot and you're done.


As you can see in the image 4 at the bottom of the post, the GPU does not appear under Graphics nor Graphics 1, but I know that it's working because the intel graphics cannot run Baldur's Gate 3 and the RTX 3050 can. (I have downloaded this game too many times this week. It was my way of verifying whether the GPU was active).
Plus, you can make sure the GPU is working with the command nvidia-smi.
Just to be clear: I don't know what caused this problem nor do I know how all this fixed it, but it did, at least for now. It's up to brighter minds to understand what the hell was going on.
God bless.
